# BPY how to detect what mode is the current mode in 3D View

Tags: python, scripting, selection-tools

I'm writing a script, trying to save the current mode that the active object is in, Object Mode or Edit Mode, in order to reset the object to that mode after running the script. The issue I'm facing is that it's a toggle, so is there a way to detect this mode and save it to a variable?

Comment: `mode = context.active_object.mode`

Comment: @batFINGER many thanks! could you put this in an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To store the mode which the active object is in you can use:

```
current_mode = bpy.context.object.mode
```

to store the mode in the variable **current_mode**. In order to set that mode again use the following line:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set ( mode = current_mode )
```

Comment: @aliasguru Nice edit, thanks, how do you add this style if you don't mind me asking? I tried opening the source but couldn't get the html behind it.

Comment: to add a code block, simply add four spaces in front of each line. This will also trigger syntax highlighting for basic Python keywords. Add two asterisks each side around something that should be bold, and one each side around things that shall be italic.